# transitioning from 16" diameter duct to rectangular return for A/C

Tags: hvac

Is there such a thing as a prefab box made of sheet-metal which is designed to fit between standard floor joists set at 16" o.c., with a round port, so that it can transition to 16" round duct up in the attic?

Comment: NO, but a good sheet metal shop will make anything your heart desires. You tell them what you want and give dimensions and they will make it .And "oh by the way", why is it off topic??  He asked a normal question and I provided a specific answer. There is always someone out there that can answer almost any question.

Answer (score 1):

Search for "*duct boot*", or "*transition*".